# Pronunciation: Vaughan Jones

Tags: terminology, mathematical-writing

Is it like "Vonn" as given here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vaughan

Comment: Yes, this is correct I think. Because, there is a famous British Cricket player by name Michael Vaughan, and I have heard the commentators pronouncing him as $\text{Vonn}$.

Comment: There are different people with the same-spelled first or family name but with unlike recent background/tradition/nationality and hence they might prefer rather different pronounciation. Pronunciation |vɔ:n| is commonly used for people with american background, including the "divine" Sarah Vaughan, the jazz singer (Vaughan as a family name). I am not sure about the New Zealand background pronouniation, like here where used as the *first* name.  

Comment: Everyone I've heard pronounce his name pronounces it this way. 

Comment: In my opinion this question is too localized (though I didn't vote to close). I think it would be better if someone opened a community wiki question asking to give the correct pronunciation of several well known mathematicians when such pronunciation may not be obvious to everybody. This could be kind of useful to the mathematical community and not take more space than a single MO question.

Comment: The vowel is longer than "Vonn" would suggest.

I'm wary of saying "pronounce it to rhyme with X" because English pronunciation varies so widely around the world. But for me (south-east of England), the vowel of Vaughan is about the same as the vowel in the word "sawn".

Comment: I think this question is hilarious, although almost certainly too localized.  I can't tell you how many times my adviser has tried to explain to me how to pronounce names like "Khovanov", and I still can't get them. @James Cranch is correct that the vowel to my ear in "Vaughan" is not quite the same vowel as in "Vonn", but they're pretty close, and you won't embarrass yourself if you use one when the other is correct. But note that even within the US there's variation in vowel pronunciation, let alone in global English. My dialect of English has 12 distinct vowel sounds and (continued)

Comment: (continuation) at least half a dozen distinct dipthongs, but other dialects of English have more (and some have fewer). A good example is that there is a vowel that in my dialect is the same as "ah", but in certain dialects in the Chicago area is different (these are the two different vowels in "cot" versus "caught", if memory serves). Another example: most dialects of English do not consciously distinguish the vowels in "right" and "time", although almost all Americans pronounce them differently (exaggerating: uh-y or ah-y), except for folks from Martha's Vineyard, for whom both are "uh-y".

Comment: Or, my favorite English vowel phenomenon: American English continues to evolve, and you can watch one of the slowest but definitely-there vowel shifts in action right now. Namely, the vowel usually spelled "oo", as in "boot", has been shifting to a vowel that I don't have a good spelling for, but in my dialect it's the vowel in "foot" or "brook" or "put". This shift started before spelling was standardized, as witnessed by "put" rather than "poot" or whatever. (Note: "foot" used to be pronounced with the vowel in "photo", hence the spelling.) And it's still happening: (continued)

Comment: (continuation) there is regional difference within the US in the vowel used in the word "roof".  I still pronounce it with a "long u", but in much of America it has shifted to the more modern pronunciation, and there are dialects where "long u" has all but died out.

Comment: I'd say Vaughan rhymes, more or less, with "lawn."

Comment: As is pointed out in the wikipedia article on the name, his is a Welsh name, meaning `little'. I would pronounce it as suggested by MTS above.

Comment: When I was in Berkeley in the 90s and his name came up, people would pronounce it to rhyme with the way I pronounce lawn, which I pronounce in an English way. But is there even a well-defined answer? I remember at school once when I was about 14 my French teacher asking me, in front of the whole class, "Is it pronounced Buzzud or Buzzaarrd?" and my not having a clue, and furthermore realising that I had no idea how to find out, and that the question had never occurred to me, and that people said both. Don't I just get to choose? If so then you just have to ask Vaughan :-) And he may not care!

Comment: The main point is if it is recognisable to be his name then that works and should be fine. The idea of correct pronunciation is very dodgy! (Even `pronunciation' is argued about!)