# How is Munkres pronounced?

Tags: terminology

How is the algebraic topologist James R. Munkres' last name "Munkres" pronounced? Is it "Munkrees" or "Munkers" or something else entirely? There is some disagreement among my acquaintances.

Apologies for the non-mathematical question. But I think that knowing the correct pronunciation is important, given Munkres has written the influential textbooks *Topology* and *Analysis on Manifolds*.

Comment: Caution.  My question on how to pronounce a name was closed http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71652/

Comment: At the very least, I feel like this should be CW. Not because there isn't a unique correct answer, but because I don't think we should reward reputation for people's opinions on a pronunciation

Comment: Hey, at least it's not a discussion of how embarrassing it is to pronounce the name of the guy who introduced the concept of building. ;-) 

Comment: @Todd: he once told me that some people pronounced it as if it rhymed with Liszt...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like Munkrehs -- the e on the end is pronounced, but as an eh rather than ee I believe.

Comment: That is what it sounded to me when he introduced himself. Definitely not "Munkers". 